# Find radius of convergence and center of this complex series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n} (z-i)^{2n}$$

My book says the answer is that the center = i, and the radius = $\sqrt{3}$

But I keep getting radius 3.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n} (z-i)^{2n}$$
so $a_{n} = \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n}$
so $a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)(n)}{3^{n+1}}$

So the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n} \cdot \frac{3^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n)}\right | = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3(n-1)}{(n+1} $

Isn't this just 3 So the radius is 3?

Comment: You're missing the $2$ in the exponent. So one term of the series out of two vanishes.

Comment: sorry can you show me?

Comment: Did you notice the exponent $2n$? So what is the value of a term with an odd exponent?

Comment: So I have to rewrite the original a term? If the z portion has to be rewritten to the nth power... how do I do this?

Comment: Define $Z = (z-i)^2$ and then study $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n} Z^n$ as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n} (z-i)^{2n}$$

Then denoting $Z=(z-i)^2$, $$f(Z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n} Z^n$$ is a power series centered on the origin.

Using the argument you developed in the question, $f(Z)$ has a radius of convergence equal to $3$.

And $$\vert Z \vert \lt 3 \iff \left\vert (z-i)^2 \right\vert \lt 3 \iff \vert z- i \vert \lt \sqrt 3$$

which means that the power series is centered on $i$ and has a radius of convergence equal to $\sqrt 3$.